# Javascript Non-Repeating Number Generator Sometimes Returns Multiple Numbers

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a random Non-Repeating Number Generator for numbers up to 13. When I run the following function I get varying out puts, here are the results of running the function 5 times using a button click, and the code. I can't understand why it's repeating some numbers.

```
var checkIfRandom = new Array();



    function getRandom(){
        var randomNum= Math.floor(Math.random()*13);
        if(checkIfRandom.indexOf(randomNum) !== -1){
            getRandom();
    }else if(checkIfRandom.indexOf(randomNum)==-1){
        checkIfRandom.push(randomNum);
    }

        console.log(randomNum);

    };

//results
2 //Click 1
7, 2 //Click 2
6 //Click 3
1 //Click 4 
5,7,1 //Click 5
[2, 7, 6, 1, 5]//After 5 clicks I logged the checkIfRandom array to the console in chrome.
```

Comment: What is expected result ?

Comment: The expected result is for it to return 1 number between 0 and 13.

Comment: Is expected result for a) `getRandom` to return _one_ random number between 0 and 13 _"The expected result is for it to return 1 number between 0 and 13"_ ? , or b) `getRandom` to return 13 non-repeating numbers from `checkIfRandom` from set 0-12 ?

Comment: That `if(checkIfRandom.indexOf(randomNum)==-1)` is superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using recursion, which means it's storing the previous, non-unique numbers in the stack and is still logging them. Move the `console.log()` into the `else if` so it reads:

```
function getRandom(){
    var randomNum= Math.floor(Math.random()*13);
    if(checkIfRandom.indexOf(randomNum) !== -1){
        getRandom();
}else if(checkIfRandom.indexOf(randomNum)==-1){
    checkIfRandom.push(randomNum);
    console.log(randomNum);
}
};
```

Comment: Just be careful as this will get stuck in an endless loop on the 14th call.

Comment: Very true. I wanted to answer using the same recursive format. Perhaps an argument could be added to getRandom() that's an incrementer and kills it all if it gets to 14?

Answer (score 0):

```
// empty array with size we want
var randomList = new Array(13).join("|").split("|");

function getRandom()
{
    // if "" doesn't exist then every number has been used
    if(randomList.indexOf("") === -1) return -1;

    // get random number
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomList.length);

    // if its already used then get a new one
    if(randomList[randomNum]) return getRandom();

    // save the random num and return it
    randomList[randomNum] = true;
    return randomNum;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vpkspna4/